# Pomelo C# : i can't import Table without Data

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I can't import with **Pomelo** on C#, a several tables without data.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "'Database'" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -Table  'table1' 'table2
```

I have an **error** :

> sequence contains no matching element

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem but i'm not sur it's good practice.

I import the all table with :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "'Database'" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql"
```

and I delete the files of others tables that I don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding a database and stating individual tables works fine with Pomelo `3.2.2`:

CLI:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;port=3306;database=So64222039" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -c MyContext --verbose -t IceCreams -t IceCreamShops
```

Package Manager:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;port=3306;database=So64222039" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -Context MyContext -Verbose -Tables IceCreams,IceCreamShops
```

The syntax to specify multiple tables is different when using the VS Package Manager instead of the CLI (use `-Tables table1,table2,table3` instead of `-t table1 -t table2 -t table3`).

Comment: In case that this is not the issue you encounter, please state what version of EF Core and Pomelo your are you using and edit your OP to contain the actual command line that you run (you can omit the connection string) instead of the sample command line call it currently shows.